# Automate Back In Stock

Tags: stock, quantity

On product pages, you know how you have

> Set Product as New from Date
>
> Set Product as New to Date

Is there something like this for Stock? So I can go into products manually, put them out of stock then set the 'back in stock date' so the product becomes live again on the website on said date?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By native Magento functionality, no.
But you can easily set up a script which you could run via cron to do this for you.

A very watered down version of your script using ORM would look a little something like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$stock_item = $product->getStockItem();
if ($stock_item->getUseConfigMinQty() == 1){
     if ($stock_item->getQty() > 0){
         $stock_item->setIsInStock(1);
         $stock_item->save();
     }
}
else{
     if ($stock_item->getQty() > $stock_item->getMinQty()){
          $stock_item->setIsInStock(1);
          $stock_item->save();
     }
}
```

The `UseConfigMinQty()` & `MinQty()` values are used on a per product basis to define a custom level at which a product becomes out of stock (i.e other than 0).

Alternately, if you're comfortable using direct SQL queries (not really recommended as no dispatch controllers would be triggered), but would make it very quick.

The table you'd want to look at is `cataloginventory_stock_item` and specifically the `qty`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `manage_stock` & `is_in_stock` columns.

Your query would look like this:

```
 $connection = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
 $connection_write = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
 $sql = 'SELECT `product_id` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` WHERE `use_config_manage_stock` = 0 AND `manage_stock` = 1 AND `qty` > 0';
 $in_stock_products = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
 foreach ($in_stock_products as $product){
     $sql = 'UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `is_in_stock` = ? WHERE `product_id` = ?';
     $connection_write->query($sql, array(1, $product['product_id']));
 }
```

Not though, that if you **are** going to use direct SQL, I'd advise you take the `use_config_min_qty` & `min_qty` fields as well (as demonstrated in the ORM example).